# LinqToTwitter: How to search tweets of users which i follow?

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter, twitter-search

LinqToTwitter: How to search tweets of users which i follow?

Using below code, I m getting results for all pubic tweets but i want to query tweets of users which i follow?

```
  var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);
     var searchResults =
         from search in twitterCtx.Search
         where search.Type == SearchType.Search
               && search.Query == txtQuery.Text
         select search;

  var searched = searchResults.SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the Twitter API doesn't offer the option you need, there are a couple things that might come close to what you want: a 'from' operator or a stream.

You can visit the [Twitter Search](https://twitter.com/search-home#) page and view the list of operators that you can include in your LINQ to Twitter Query. One of these operators is 'from'. This appears to be only a single user, but it sounds like you want all of your followers. Anyway, you can experiment on the [Twitter Search](https://twitter.com/search-home#) page to see what results you get and then translate that into the LINQ to Twitter Query.

Another approach might be to use a [Filter Stream](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Filtered%20Statuses&referringTitle=Streaming%20Twitter%20Content). It has a Follow property that takes a comma-separated list of users. With the Search above, you're doing request/response. However, streams are different in that you open the connection and listen for a long time, processing responses as they arrive.